# Python 3 subprocess SIGABRT

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.6

I am trying to use subprocess.Popen to run a Node.js tool that eventually SSH's into another machine. When I run it in Python 2, everything works fine. However, when I run the exact same command through Python 3, it crashed with an error code -6 (I've used check_output to determine that it's dying with SIBABRT).

Now, here's the weirder part. If I run the subprocess command through the python3 terminal, it will work without a hitch. However, when I add a Node.js wrapper around the outside of it (part of the software I work on, nothing I can do about it), that's when it breaks. Python 2 works with the Node.js wrapper. I'm honestly not sure what it could be at this point.

Here is the code (not showing command because it's an internal tool):

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
output,stderr_data = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    logging.error('return code')
    logging.error( "-----%r failed, status code %r" % (cmd, p.returncode) + "------")
    raise RuntimeError('%r failed, status code %s' % (cmd, p.returncode))
```

I've tried checking stderr and stdout, but they both appear to be completely empty.

I am running Python 3.6.4, Python 2.7.5, Node 6.9.1, and CentOS 7

EDIT: It appears the SIGABRT happens any time I try and run ANY node command through Popen. I tried replacing cmd with ['node'] and ['node', 'test_node.js'] and both die with SIGABRT...

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same behavior and the solution was getting rid of pm2 as a top-level program runner.

I had the following setup:

```
pm2-runtime
    v
python app with subprocess.run('node ...')
    v
nodejs app
```

Without `pm2-runtime`, `subprocess.run` works with nodejs just fine.